# Inserting the data from tableview to array in iphone app

Tags: iphone

I am making an iPhone app. In this app I have used tableview which shows local notifications timing whenever I press the datetime picker. Now I want to store all the values of tableview in to an array. How can I do this. Please give me some solutions.

We have implemented the Local notification and uses PickerView for it to set the data on the rows in tableview. This is the code snippet for displaying the data in tableview:-       - (IBAction) scheduleAlarm:(id) sender {
    [eventText resignFirstResponder];

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];

// Get the current date
NSDate *pickerDate = [self.datePicker date];

// Break the date up into components
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:( NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit ) 
                                               fromDate:pickerDate];
NSDateComponents *timeComponents = [calendar components:( NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit ) 
                                               fromDate:pickerDate];

// Set up the fire time
NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateComps setDay:[dateComponents day]];
[dateComps setMonth:[dateComponents month]];
[dateComps setYear:[dateComponents year]];
[dateComps setHour:[timeComponents hour]];
// Notification will fire in one minute
[dateComps setMinute:[timeComponents minute]];
//[dateComps setSecond:[timeComponents second]];
NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];
[dateComps release];

UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
if (localNotif == nil)
    return;
localNotif.fireDate = itemDate;
localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

// Notification details
localNotif.alertBody = [eventText text];
// Set the action button
localNotif.alertAction = @"View";

localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

// Specify custom data for the notification
NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"someValue" forKey:@"someKey"];
localNotif.userInfo = infoDict;

// Schedule the notification
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
[localNotif release];

[self.tableview reloadData];
```

}

Comment: why dnt you use your tableview's data source it is an array !!! or you want to store any selected row's data ?

Comment: Please provide me with the example how to use this to fill all the data from tableview dataSource in the array.

Comment: how your felling data into the table view ???

Comment: We have implemented the Local notification and uses PickerView for it to set the data on the rows in tableview. Snippet code has been added in the question. Please look into it and provide me the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should create a custom class and define the all this variables as property. then in 
 `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

method create a new object of that class and assign all these value accordingly. after that in any mutable array add this custom objects. n yes take care of duplications.